# How to match an input value to a matrix form data?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I got a data of safety factor and its corresponding force, I wan to make it like prompting and asking ''what is the safety factor?' then the user will enter the value of safety factor and I wan an output displays the corresponding force in the data table

thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to search a value in first column and print the corresponding value from second column you can do something like this:

```
ri = find(A(:,1) == y);
z = A(ri,2);
```

This assumes that you will always find the corresponding value of `y` in first column of `A`. If that is not the case, you need to modify the code:

```
ri = find(A(:,1) == y);
if isempty(ri)            % value not found
    % code to print error message 
    % or
    % code interpolate between given values 
else
    z = A(ri,2);
end
```

you can also use `try-catch` block instead of `if-else` statement.

Interpolation can be bit trick as you need to model it correctly. It is still much easier to interpolate than extrapolate.
Assuming your the values in first column are arranged in increasing or decreasing order, you can use `interp1` as follows, for first order interpolation,

z = interp1( A(:,1), A(:,2) , y);

Comment: note that the `==` comparison will only work if the values in first column of `A` are integer if you have numbers with fractional part then it needs to be corrected. If you can post some actual values/text cases then it will be easier to help.

Comment: @green you should upvote helpful answers and comments. that is a better way to show thanks. also if you find the right answer click on the arrow to accept is as final answer.

Comment: Oh ya one more question, if I wan to do the interpolate, do I need to program every condition since the input y is an key-in data. For eg. 
A = [1,2;3,5;6,7] do I need to model it as
if y>1 & y<2; z = interpl ...
elseif y>3 & y<5; z = interpl..something like tat
is there any eaiser command can be applied? thanks

Comment: @green i have updated the answer to provide one way to interpolate

Comment: alright really thanks a lot..I'll vote it when I get enough reputation point..thank you again=)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are simply wanting to index the value. Matlab indexes start at 1, so you either need to use that as your reference, or add one. The correct was is to put the desired index in parenthesis, as so

```
output_value=A(y+1);
```

Comment: Actually I got a data table of two variables(eg. x and y) and I want to match it with my key in data, if my key in data is listed in x then I wan a output value be the y value corresponding to x. How can I model it using matlab..hmm

Comment: Just be careful that since matlab stores values in "column first order". This means that A(2) = 3 not 2 and A(4) = 3 not 5. Most other languages like C and python store values in "row first order".

Comment: @TeeYeesiang can you give a better example of what you want to do.

Comment: I got a data of safety factor and its corresponding force, I wan to make it like prompting and asking ''what is the safety factor?' then the user will enter the value of safety factor and I wan an output displays the corresponding force in the data table.

Comment: @TeeYeesiang if I understand correctly, you want to search for a value in first column of `A` and then print out the corresponding value from second column. The way the question is posed it is not clear that this is what you want to do. I would suggest adding the previous comment to the question to make it more clear. I will try to post an other answer.

Comment: @mythealias ya that's my problem...sry for not defining the problem in a good way..so is there any function that can be used to program it?